# Using colormap in cycle (python)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to edit the for cycles under #ax5 and #ax6 to plot graphs in the same fashion? Now, the lower figure has no colour transit, as opposed to the upper one. The colour transit appears in the lower figure after increasing of dpi, however, some unwanted stuff also appears. Is there a scalling problem? Thank you

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import math
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

# Function for plotting parallels to curves
def get_parallels(length=.1):
    
    px, py = [], []
    
    for idx in range(len(x)-1):
        x0, y0, xa, ya = x[idx], y[idx], x[idx+1], y[idx+1]
        dx, dy = xa-x0, ya-y0
        norm = math.hypot(dx, dy) * 1/length
        dx /= norm
        dy /= norm        
        px.append(x0-dy)
        py.append(y0+dx)
    return px, py

def offset(x,y, o):
    """ Offset coordinates given by array x,y by o """
    X = np.c_[x,y].T
    m = np.array([[0,-1],[1,0]])
    R = np.zeros_like(X)
    S = X[:,2:]-X[:,:-2]
    R[:,1:-1] = np.dot(m, S)
    R[:,0] = np.dot(m, X[:,1]-X[:,0])
    R[:,-1] = np.dot(m, X[:,-1]-X[:,-2])
    On = R/np.sqrt(R[0,:]**2+R[1,:]**2)*o
    Out = On+X
    return Out[0,:], Out[1,:]

dpi = 20

def offset_curve(ax, x,y, o):
    """ Offset array x,y in data coordinates
        by o in points """
    trans = ax.transData.transform
    inv = ax.transData.inverted().transform
    X = np.c_[x,y]
    Xt = trans(X)
    xto, yto = offset(Xt[:,0],Xt[:,1],o*dpi/72. )
    Xto = np.c_[xto, yto]
    Xo = inv(Xto)
    return Xo[:,0], Xo[:,1]


fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

gs = GridSpec(3, 6, figure=fig)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 3:6])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, :3])
ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 3:6])

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greys_r')

# ax5
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = -x**2
ax5.set_ylim(-1.02, 0.3)
width_l = ax5.get_ylim()[1] - ax5.get_ylim()[0]
for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 40): 
    length =  -0.1*width_l*t
    ax5.plot(*get_parallels(length=length), color=cmap(t/2 + 0.25))

# ax6
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = -(1/4*x**4 - 1.6*x**2) 
ax6.plot(x, y)
ax6.set_xlim(ax6.get_xlim()[0]-0.5, ax6.get_xlim()[1]+0.5)
ax6.scatter(1/2*(ax6.get_xlim()[0] + ax6.get_xlim()[1]), 1.2, marker = 'o', s=900, facecolors='none')
lines = []
width_l = ax6.get_ylim()[1] - ax6.get_ylim()[0]
for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 40):
    l, = ax6.plot(x, y - t * 0.1 * width_l, color=cmap(t/2 + 0.25))
    lines.append(l)

def plot_rainbow(event=None):
    x0 = x
    y0 = y
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        xx, yy = offset_curve(ax, x0, y0, -width_l)
        lines[i].set_data(xx, yy)
        lines[i].set_linewidth(1.1*width_l)
        x0 = xx
        y0 = yy

plot_rainbow()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", plot_rainbow)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", plot_rainbow)
plt.savefig('fig.pdf')
```